# How do I monitor iAd performance in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

Sorry, I'm not entirely sure if this question is appropriate so delete if necessary, I just haven't had any success with Apple or Google!

I've successfully implemented iAd into my app and live ads are being pushed to the app which can be seen. However, I can't seem to find how I find how the ads are doing. How many impressions they get and how much they are earning.

Is there such a feature within iTunes Connect which I can't see? Or do I need to wait until Apple sends out the payment to find out how much they've earned?

Thanks,

Comment: here is very good tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/iad-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the URL here, apparently Apple hide the URL:

https://iad.apple.com/itcportal